# R - Ordering using do.call with descending order

Tags: r, do.call

I want to order a dataset based on an user input.
The user input will be a char array (of column name), called cols below.

```
dataset1[do.call('order', as.list(dataset1[cols])),]
```

This works fine. I'm trying to add the ordering direction (descending or ascending) too but I keep getting the same error: "unused argument (descending = TRUE)".

Anyone can help me setting the ordering direction while using a char[] of columns?

Comment: Try `dataset1[do.call('order', c(dataset1[cols], list(decreasing=TRUE))),]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can place the extra argument in a `list`, concatenate the dataset with that and use `do.call`

```
dataset1[do.call('order', c(dataset1[cols], list(decreasing=TRUE))),]
```