# Quasiquotation Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 144000

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I want to pass in a list of columns into the arrange function. I tried using enquos function

where column.names is

```
column.names <- c(colnames(SQL_Table))
column.names
 [1] "plan"           "class"          "gender"         "band"           "marital_status" "acceleration"   "extension"     
 [8] "inflation"      "iss_age"        "cell"           "dur"            "db_perk"        "accel_perk"     "ext_perk"      
[15] "attage"
```

and my code is

```
column.names <- c(colnames(SQL_Table))

arrange.remove <- c("cell","db_perk","accel_perk","ext_perk","attage","db_perk_compare")
arrange.columns <- setdiff(column.names,remove)
arrange_quo <-  enquos(arrange.columns)

SQL_Table %>%
  arrange(!!arrange_quo)
```

I am getting the error

```
Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 144000
```

Comment: You need `rlang::syms` instead of `enquos` and the splicing operator `!!!`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004217/r-ordering-using-do-call-with-descending-order) you can use construction:

```
cols.names <- colnames(df)
df[do.call('order', df[cols.names]), ]
df[do.call('order', c(df[cols.names], list(decreasing=TRUE))), ]
```

So in case of using pipeline:

```
df %>% 
  .[do.call("order", .[cols.names]), ]
```

However for single column name also works:

```
col.name <- "column.name"
df %>%
  arrange(.[[get("col.name")]])
```